# TranslateAnimation with nested layouts

Tags: android, animation

I am setting up a "menu expand" animation. The expanding options are 2 `RelativeLayout` nested in a vertical `LinearLayout`. The `TranslateAnimation` is applied to the surrounding `LinearLayout` and makes the options expand from the bottom.

The problem is that only the first nested `RelativeLayout` is displayed. The second just becomes visible without animation.

Below, the XML layout in question, the method applying the animation, and the call.
Thank you very much for your thoughts

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bmb_navigation_expanded"
    style="@style/bmb_RelativeLayout"
    android:layout_above="@id/bmb_bottom_bar"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <RelativeLayout
        style="@style/bmb_RelativeLayout">

     option 1 stuff

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout            
        style="@style/bmb_RelativeLayout">

     option 2 stuff

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Method applying the animation to the LinearLayout:

```
    public static void setSlideIn(ViewGroup panel, Context ctx) {

      AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(false);

      Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(
          Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
          Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f
      );
      animation.setDuration(200);
      set.addAnimation(animation);

      LayoutAnimationController controller = new LayoutAnimationController(set, 0);
      panel.setLayoutAnimation(controller);

    }
```

This is how I call the animation:

```
        layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        setSlideIn(layout, getActivity());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here. `LayoutAnimationController`  distributes the animation to all `ViewGroup` childs. If I want to animate the `ViewGroup` as a single entity I must do the following:

```
panel.setAnimation(set);
set.start();
```